# Updating python numpy array columns multiple times

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Suppose I have a 2x3 matrix `A`:

```
1 2 3   
4 5 6
```

and a vector `y` of length 4:

```
0 1 2 1
```

as well as another 4x2 matrix `B`:

```
0 0  
1 1   
2 2   
3 3
```

I want to update the columns of `A` multiple times by adding from rows of `B`.
And the index of columns of `A` to be updated is given by `y`.

Using `for` loops, this can be done as:

```
for i in np.arange(4):
  A[:,y[i]] += B[i,:]
```

I had implemented this using `ufunc.at` as:

```
np.add.at(A.T,y,B)
```

However, the performance of `ufunc.at` is almost as bad as using `for` loops.

**How can I get a different vectorized implementation?**

Updating using `A[:,y]+=B.T` seems to update each column only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Here's one approach using summations at intervals with [`np.add.reduceat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) -

```
def reduceat_app(A, y, B):
    idx = y.argsort()
    y0 = y[idx]
    sep_idx = np.concatenate(([0], np.flatnonzero(y0[1:] != y0[:-1])+1))
    A += np.add.reduceat(B[idx],sep_idx).T
```

**Approach #2**

With relatively lesser number of rows in `A`, we can also use [`np.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) to perform those bin-based summations in an iterative manner for each row, like so -

```
def bincount_loopy_app(A, y, B): 
    n = A.shape[1]
    for i,a in enumerate(A):
        a += np.bincount(y,B[:,i],minlength=n).astype(A.dtype)
```

**Approach #3**

We can vectorize previous approach by creating a `2D` grid of `y` indices/bins for all elements such that for each row, we would have offsetted bins. With that offsetting, `bincount` could be used to perform bin based summations across all rows in a vectorized manner.

Thus, the implementation would be -

```
def bincount_vectorized_app(A, y, B): 
    m,n = A.shape
    IDs = y[:,None] + n*np.arange(B.shape[1])
    vals = np.bincount(IDs.ravel(), B.ravel(), minlength=m*n)
    A += vals.astype(A.dtype).reshape((m,n))
```